# Components not rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, styling, pinia

I wonder why the Components are not rendered. While the console isn't showing any of the typical errors.

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jasper-teh1im?file=/src/components/Form.vue**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <KeepAlive>
      <component :is="currentStep" />
    </KeepAlive>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ["currentStep"],
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `currentStep` as a prop in your `<Form />` component and instead of method use computed property to pass the component name dynamically.

```
computed: {
    currentStep() {
      return this.steps[this.stepIndex];
    },
  }
```

Live Demo **:** [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-butterfly-71e91o?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't passed `currentStep` to `Form` in `App.vue`

Please fix the following and it will work:

- Delete `currentStep` from `methods` in `App.vue`
- Add `computed` `currentStep` to `App.vue`:

```
...
  computed: {
    currentStep() {
      return this.steps[this.stepIndex]
    }
  }
...
```

- add prop `currentStep` to `Form` in `App.vue`:

```js
...
<Form
  ...
  :current-step="currentStep"
/>
...
```

> also you should consider the new syntax of vue 3 or sfc

> avoid using `provide` your code is crashing switch to `props`